# Functional testing with Spring Security plugin in a Grails app

Tags: grails, spring-security, junit4, functional-testing, geb

I have a secured grails application with the spring security plugin and right now I am trying to do some tests with the login process with no success till now. Has anybody an idea of what is the problem?

This is my LoginPage.groovy

```
package pages.login

import geb.Page


class LoginPage extends Page {
    static url = "login/auth"

    static at = {
        title ==~ /Login/
    }

    static content = {
        loginForm { $("form") }
        username { $("input", type:"text", name:"j_username") }
        password { $("input", type:"password", name:"j_password") }
        loginButton{ $("input", type:"submit", value:"Login") }
    }
}
```

And this is the test using junit4:

```
import geb.junit4.GebReportingTest

import pages.copyright.*
import pages.login.LoginPage
import org.junit.Test

class CopyrightCRUDTests extends GebReportingTest {

    @Test
    void doSomeCrud() {

        to LoginPage
        at LoginPage
        $("form").j_username() << "admin"
        $("form").j_password() << "XXXXX"
        loginButton.click()

        to AuthenticatedPage
        at AuthenticatedPage

    }
}
```

The AuthenticatedPage is a page which needs authentication, but in this moment it is imposible to be authenticated using geb. Does anybody know anything about this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's the error you are getting? use firefox driver and see what is going on...

Comment: You shouldn't need this: to AuthenticatedPage

Comment: Also `at LoginPage` is unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting `doSomeCrud()` as follows:

```
to LoginPage
loginForm.j_username = 'admin'
loginForm.j_password = 'XXXXX'
loginButton.click()
waitFor { at AuthenticatedPage }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you since you are not using Spock, but I had a few issues with login as well (can't remember exactly what though)

I eventually found this code that I put in a spec extending GebSpec.

This gets called before each of the tests requiring a login:

```
  def setupSpec() {
    Browser.drive {
      go baseUrl
        $("form.login").with {
          username = System.getenv("APP_USERNAME")
          password = System.getenv("APP_PASSWORD")
        }
        $("input[name='submit']").click()
      }
  }
```

It doesn't seem like much, but the use of 'with' on the form worked for me.